# Set default value of DatePicker in DataGrid column

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I Have a DataGrid bound to a Collection, one of the columns type is DateTime.

my xaml code is:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="260" Header="OrderDate">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding OrderDate,
                                       Mode=TwoWay,
                                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

the problem is the DatePicker default value is 1/1/0001.

how do I set the default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was fixed this way(sorry if the question wasn't clear):

in the class declaration:

```
public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
```

change it to:

```
public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
```

it look like it was taking the DateTime dfault value and the solution was to add nulls instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    // Default value
    private DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime(2010, 1, 18);

    public string Sample
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime OrderDate
    {
        get
        {
            return myDateTime;
        }

        set
        {
            myDateTime = value;
        }
    }
}
```

After adding the data, for example - in `ObservableCollection`:

```
SomeCollection.Add(new SomeClass()
{            
    Sample = "Sample1",
    OrderDate = DateTime.Now, // Forcibly set date
});
```

When skipping of this parameter is added to the default value:

```
SomeCollection.Add(new Person()
{            
    Sample = "Sample1",
    // Skipping date, set the default value "2010, 1, 18"
});
```